# Lumia 930: Error 801881e4 when checking for update?

Tags: update, lumia-denim-update, nokia-lumia-930

I have a Lumia 930 which is on Cyan. Whenever I check for updates, it gives this error:

> We are currently unable to check for updates. (801881e4)

I've searched and the only solution provided in forums, ... is setting the correct date+time. I have set it correctly (switching off setting it automatically) and checked it again and again with no luck!

Does anyone know a solution to this annoying problem?

Comment: Are any other Microsoft services not working correctly (store, outlook)?

Comment: @Thomas, outlook account syncs (after some retries). But store also gives error: `we are currently unable to perform your request` (or something like this) with error code: 80070020

Comment: This could acutally be a temporary issue with Microsoft services. Since when is this a problem for you?

Comment: @Thomas, I doubt it. I checked with a Lumia 520 (previously updated to Denim) and both the update checking and app downloading works fine. I just bought this phone yesterday and it has the problem since the first boot...

Comment: Have you gone to Settings > Email + Accounts and tried syncing the account, or making sure there are no errors with it?

Comment: @Shawn, the Outlook account shows no error and syncs fine. But still getting errors in both update and store...

Comment: I assume you've restarted it?

Comment: @Shawn, restarted, soft reset, hard reset, you name it, I did it! But to no avail...

Comment: did you try this both using wifi and your mobile data connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I was able to solve the problem. I thought I put it here so it may help others as well.

The issue was actually with the date+time and the outlook account, but not like the forums suggested:

The problem was that I had set up the account **manually (from settings, not from when accessing store, ... asks to sign in)** and set the date+time **after** the account was already set up.

So, here's how it was solved:

1. I deleted the account from settings.
2. I made sure date and time was correct.
3. I opened the store and it asked for the account, so I sign it right there and ... voila! Everything was working!